# SQL timestamp field reading as Widestring

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I wrote an application that uses a TFDQuery to retrieve data from a SQL Server. A few of the fields in the query are typed as TSQLTimeStampField. Everything works beautifully when I run the application, either from within the Delphi IDE or as a standalone app.

However, when my colleague, who needs to use the application, tries to run it, she gets this error, also shown in the attached image.

**Exception EOleException in module AnalysisResults.exe at 0066F98A.
fdqResults: Type mismatch for field 'CollectionTime', expecting: TimeStamp actual: WideString.**

[image]

We're using version 2019 of SQL Server, and the data field in the SQL table is typed as DateTime2(0).

I'm at a loss as to how to remedy this. Any suggestions?

I tried changing the field to WideString, but that was a non-starter, which I expected.

I also tried changing the field to DateTime, but again, I got a Debugger Exception:

**Project AnalyseesResults_SQL.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'fdqResults: Type mismatch for field 'CollectionTime', expecting: DateTime actual: Timestamp'.**

[image]

Comment: `timestamp` isn't a date and time data type, it's a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value; it has *nothing* to do with date and times,.

Comment: What driver is colleague using? Down level drivers, such as the ODBC and OLE DB drivers that ship with Windows are unaware of newer types like datetime2 and return strings instead.

Comment: Thom A - The field is DateTime2(0) in SQL Server; when accessed via TFDQuery, it autmatically types as TSQLTimestampField.

Comment: Dan Guzman - Not sure about colleague's drivers. Her workstation is newer than mine, but she keeps tight reins and I don't have ready access to it.

Comment: Edit your question. Put an @ in front of users you're addressing. Take the [tour]. Don't re-type error dialog texts - press `Ctrl+C` instead and paste the text from the clipboard.

Comment: How did you create the database?  Is it the same, was it created twice manually.  Was it restored from backup? was it created from script?

Comment: It was my colleague's driver. Once the updated driver was installed, voila!